Staging Ground edits don't have a grace period
I just edited a Staging Ground question's tags, then I noticed some typos and fixed them too, then noticed a typo I missed and fixed it. Each time I clicked the edit button created a new revision, but if this had been a regular question, all three would have been bundled together because I made them within 5 minutes.
Is this intentional or is it a bug? I can imagine it might be intentional so that the editing process is more straightforward when new users look at it.

This has previously been reported in the beta testing team, received an issue ID and was marked [status-planned] so I think there's a good chance of it being fixed (link for users with access).

Honestly I prefer the system without a grace period. Grace period enables abuse and the benefit is negligible. Devs, please don't fix this.

@TylerH I've never seen abuse myself, but I've certainly seen confusing changes caused by a "race condition" of sorts where one person edits, another starts edits during the grace period (usually the OP in my experience), the first person does another edit during the grace period which gets combined with the first edit, then the second person finishes editing, undoing the first person's second edit.

Which is a reason why edits on Q/A should lock a post from other users editing for some period of time (like SG does), but sadly that request of mine did not receive much attention--though the issue of conflicting edits is orthogonal to a grace period.
